# How to approach this problem by directly using line integral and the Green's Theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

The question No 4 is asking to use methods: one just directly solving by line integral and another is by using Green's Theorem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?